# Why doesn't std::shared_ptr dereference throw a null pointer exception (or similar)?

Tags: c++, exception

Exceptions are a big part of C++ and one of the reasons to use it (I know there are many, more important, other reasons) is to avoid needless checks that obfuscate code with a lot of `if` statements (maybe this is an incorrect assumption?).

So now I am curious as to why `std::shared_ptr::operator*` and `std::shared_ptr::operator->` do not throw a `null_ptr_exception` or similar?

Comment: Did you find an implementation of a smart pointer that does the described behaviour?

Comment: @aggsol, no, we ended up making our own using existing implementation and template policies

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My understanding is that the smart pointer classes are designed to look and behave like raw pointers. Given this guiding design principal, ideally legacy code could simply replace usage of raw pointers with smart pointers using equivalent ownership semantics and the code would work exactly as before.

Therefore, changing the behavior for dereferencing smart pointers should not do any additional checks or throw exceptions (i.e., since raw pointers don't behave this way).

The proposal to add smart pointers to the standard indicates this design decision ([A Proposal to Add General Purpose Smart Pointers to the Library Technical Report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1450.html)):

> III. Design Decisions
>
> A. General Principles
>
> 1. "As Close to Raw Pointers as Possible, but no Closer"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I must admit that the reason from the standard's committee is not satisfactory. If we do replace legacy code with smart pointers, then a `null_ptr_exception` will be unhandled and the program will break anyway (just like an assertion, although granted without the unwinding - then again, just like an assertion, this exception can be broken into by a debugger).

Comment: @Samaursa For a raw pointer dereferencing a null pointer triggers Undefined Behavior and the program may appear to run perfectly normally but I understand your point of view and frustration.

Comment: I don't like the design. Maybe we should have another modern smarter pointer.

Answer (score 7):

If every dereference of a shared pointer was required to check for `nullptr` and conditionally throw an exception, there could be a lot of redundant checks, code bloat and overhead.  Sure - the optimiser's likely to eliminate some of that, but still....  Instead, the programmer's expected to check once before however-many dereferences.

Comment: But isn't that the argument for/against exceptions/error-codes?

Comment: @Samaursa: no... dereferencing a raw pointer or Standard Library smart pointer is allowed to generate machine code that assumes the pointer will never be nullptr - that machine code will run faster than code that has to  check and avoid (for the same non-nullptr cases) branching to the error handling code.  Not checking/branching is faster, regardless of whether that handling is reached using an exception or error code (which themselves may vary in speed and machine code size).

Comment: I would expect `unique_ptr` to have an assertion and `shared_ptr` (since it is already quite a heavy object with reference counting and tracking `weak_ptr`s) to `throw`. Nevertheless, it makes sense as a pointer dereference is an extremely common operation.

Comment: @Samaursa: anyone can easily wrap a pointer to add checking in their own code, but if it were baked in you could never get the speed back.  It's also desirable that people can migrate from raw pointer usage to `unique_ptr` knowing there's no risk of reduced performance (well, they should probably run an eye over their implementation once, but after that)... saves a lot of performance profiling around such changes.  And let's say `unique_ptr` did `assert`... anyone wanting their program not to be halted would then have to check for `nullptr` themselves and throw, so there's double checking.