# Is there a safe navigation operator for C++?

Tags: c++, c++17

In Modern C++, is there a way to do safe navigation?

For example, *instead* of doing...

```
if (p && p->q && p->q->r)
    p->q->r->DoSomething();
```

...having a succinct syntax by using some sort of short-circuiting smart pointer, or some other kind of syntax leveraging operator overloading, or something in the Standard C++ Library, or in Boost.

```
p?->q?->r?->DoSomething(); // C++ pseudo-code.
```

Context is C++17 in particular.

Comment: Not as far as i know, and hopefully it will not appear. This style of coding a->b->c->d leads to big problems, tight coupling, and inability to separate pieces of code from each other.

Comment: What should the safe pointer do in which case?

Comment: You could overload `operator->` but the question is what it should return.

Comment: @Bogolt - I agree with the "big problems" aspect on all points mentioned.

Unfortunately, my situation is working with a very large and very old code base that uses the first example as a pattern pervasively.  Except in the places that were missed.  I have first hand experience of the big problems.

Given time, the code base should become better encapsulated and employ the "tell, don't ask" principle.  But that is in the future.

Comment: @manni66 - the "safe navigation operator" should short-circuit and be a no-op.

Comment: With the optional monad and `boost::make_optional` shortcut to `b::mo`, you could probably code this as `b::mo(p, p) >>= [](auto *p) { return b::mo(p->q, p->q) >>= [](auto *q) { return b::mo(q->r, q->r) >>= [](auto *r) { return r->DoSomething(), b::none(); }; }; }`

Comment: I must say, that I'm not sure whether that's any better. With macros, you could maybe shorten it to `if(auto o = OPT(p, p->q, q->r)) (*o)->DoSomething(); ` ? Where the `MODO` would generate that nested lambda lattice and insert the macro arguments into the second and third arguments of `b::mo` respectively?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb - The boost::optional is an interesting and cool facility.  Thanks for bringing it to my attention!  A small page out of the OCaml or Haskell playbooks:  monads (or a C++ facsimile thereof)!  It would fast-fail, much like Richard Hodges' answer.  But the callsite would be as cluttered as Barry's answer... I concur with what you said "I'm not sure whether that's any better."

Comment: A coworker said "So the problem is getting a segmentation fault.  How about a smart pointer that throws an exception that you could handle gracefully.  You could even put a breakpoint in it if it is in a nullptr state and being dereferenced, and have guaranteed nullptr initialization.  The exception would short-circuit the rest of the pointer chain."  Well it isn't a safe navigation operator, but may very well be a reasonable solution... perhaps I was blinded by CoffeeScript / Groovy / C# envy.

Comment: The C++ standard library smart pointers, and the boost smart pointers don't throw.  I'll just have to roll my own as a one-off.  q.v. [Why doesn't std::shared_ptr dereference throw a null pointer exception (or similar)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409299/why-doesnt-stdshared-ptr-dereference-throw-a-null-pointer-exception-or-simil)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best you can do is collapse all the member accesses into one function. This assumes without checking that everything is a pointer:

```
template <class C, class PM, class... PMs>
auto access(C* c, PM pm, PMs... pms) {
    if constexpr(sizeof...(pms) == 0) {
        return c ? std::invoke(pm, c) : nullptr;
    } else {
        return c ? access(std::invoke(pm, c), pms...) : nullptr;
    }
}
```

Which lets you write:

```
if (auto r = access(p, &P::q, &Q::r); r) {
    r->doSomething();
}
```

That's ok. Alternatively, you could go a little wild with operator overloading and produce something like:

```
template <class T>
struct wrap {
    wrap(T* t) : t(t) { }
    T* t;

    template <class PM>
    auto operator->*(PM pm) {
        return ::wrap{t ? std::invoke(pm, t) : nullptr};
    }

    explicit operator bool() const { return t; }
    T* operator->() { return t; }
};
```

which lets you write:

```
if (auto r = wrap{p}->*&P::q->*&Q::r; r) {
    r->doSomething();
}
```

That's also ok. There's unfortunately no `->?` or `.?` like operator, so we kind of have to work around the edges.

Comment: :)) While absolutely correct, `auto r = wrap{p}->*&P::q->*&Q::r; r` is about as legible as an ancient manuscript in a long-forgotten tongue, buried under thousands of years of dust, having been feasted on by two hundred generations of maggots - in a locked crypt that no-one has yet discovered.

Comment: I took your comment to heart, and replaced my answer with a better one - for comedy effect if nothing else :)

Comment: Would an overload `access(C &, PM pm. PMs... pms)` allow it to chain references? (and similar for value returning members?)

Comment: That's cool. Does it allow calling member functions, with `->*std::bind(&P::f, _1, args)` ?

Comment: @Barry - that's very cool template metaprogramming!  And I learned something!  I slightly prefer the 1st "access" approach you posted over the 2nd "wrap" approach (for the humorous reason Richard Hodges mentioned), but I grok that the 2nd may be arguably better C++ since the relationship is explicit.  But the callsite use case is not any better than the "by hand" C++ to check for a valid pointer chain.

Comment: I marking Barry's answer as the accepted answer because of this part "There's unfortunately no ->? or .? like operator..."  Thanks everyone for thinking about my question!  If someone comes up with a way to better mimic a safe navigation operator in C++, that'd be awesome.

Comment: @Eljay Yeah frankly what you had originally is what I would actually use in production code.

Answer (score 6):

#### "With a little Boilerplate..."

We can get to this:

`p >> q >> r >> doSomething();`

Here's the boilerplate...

```
#include <iostream>

struct R {
    void doSomething()
    {
        std::cout << "something\n";
    }
};

struct Q {
    R* r;
};

struct P {
    Q* q;
};

struct get_r {};
constexpr auto r = get_r{};

struct get_q {};
constexpr auto q = get_q{};

struct do_something {
    constexpr auto operator()() const {
        return *this;
    }
};
constexpr auto doSomething = do_something {};

auto operator >> (P* p, get_q) -> Q* {
    if (p) return p->q;
    else return nullptr;
}

auto operator >> (Q* q, get_r) -> R* {
    if (q) return q->r;
    else return nullptr;
}

auto operator >> (R* r, do_something)
{
    if (r) r->doSomething();
}

void foo(P* p)
{
//if (p && p->q && p->q->r)
//    p->q->r->DoSomething();
    p >> q >> r >> doSomething();
}
```

The resulting assembly is very acceptable. The journey to this point may not be...

```
foo(P*):
        test    rdi, rdi
        je      .L21
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        test    rax, rax
        je      .L21
        cmp     QWORD PTR [rax], 0
        je      .L21
        mov     edx, 10
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
        jmp     std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
.L21:
        ret
```

Comment: Doesn't short-circuit, but it does fast-fail.  The boilerplate could be stuffed into a macro (albeit I'm not a fan of macros).  I like how it is used by the caller at the callsite -- very clean, even though it wouldn't "idiomatic C++" for pointer dereferencing.

Comment: @Eljay The optimiser does the short-circuiting for us, so that's not a problem. You'll probably want a code generator to do it for an entire project. You could build that quite quickly with a tool like `yacc`.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc

Answer (score 2):

although it's 2022 now, there's still no language level support for this.
a very close simulation I can figure out:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
auto operator->*(T&& t, F&& f) {
  return f(std::forward<T>(t));
}

#define pcall(fn)                                                            \
  [&](auto&& __p) {                                                          \
    if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(__p)>>) \
      return __p ? __p->fn : decltype(__p->fn){};                            \
    else                                                                     \
      return __p ? __p.fn : decltype(__p.fn){};                              \
  }

struct A {
  int v;
  int foo(int a, int b) { return a + b + v; }
};
struct B {
  A* getA() { return &a; }
  A a{100};
};
struct C {
  B* getB() { return &b; }
  B b;
  operator bool() { return true; }
};

int main(){
    int v = 3;

    C by_val;
    int t1 = by_val->*pcall(getB())->*pcall(getA())->*pcall(foo(1, v));

    C* by_ptr = &by_val;
    int t2 = by_ptr->*pcall(getB())->*pcall(getA())->*pcall(foo(1, v));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zPhzTTv9s

Comment: Nice, I like employing the `->*` overload.  (In toy programs (not real programs!), I've (ab)used that to facilitate C#-like extension methods.)