C++ equivalent of Javascript's '?.' operator for optional-chaining?
In Javascript, if I have a potentially null object obj, which, if not null, will have a field x - I can write obj?.x. This is called "optional chaining" or "safe navigation": If obj is null, or otherwise not an object with accessible fields - it won't throw, just produce null. (It also won't throw if obj is an object but doesn't have an x field, although that's less relevant for this question).
Now let us turn to C++, which since C++17 has standard-library std::optional<T>'s. Suppose we have:
struct Foo { Bar x; }

and I have an optional<Foo> object named obj. Naively, I might write the expression:
obj ? obj->x : optional<Bar>{}

... but this won't work, since the types of the two result expression is different, and the trinary operator doesn't harmonize them.  Godbolt confirms, with this code:
#include <optional>

using Bar = int;
struct Foo { Bar x; };

std::optional<Bar> f()
{
    std::optional<Foo> obj {};
    return obj ? obj->x : std::nullopt;
}

So, what short idiom is there for expressing obj?.x in C++?

Note: Any language standard version is fine, but the older the better obviously.

return obj ? std::optional{obj->x} : std::nullopt; will work

and of course you could use a macro to reduce the boiler plate

C++ doesn't provide sugar for null-chaining

Using if might be almost as the question proposed code: if (!obj) return {}; if (!obj->x) return {}; return obj->x->y;  You have to write return more times, but can leave out optional<Bar>.

What's wrong with std::optional<Bar> result; if (obj) result = obj->x; return result;?    ?: in C++ may look superficially like ?. in Javascript, but it is quite different.

@NathanOliver: See my answer about using a macro.

@Peter: 1. It's not an expression. 2. Difficult to chain further. 3. Long. 4. Lame :-(

@BenVoigt: Not an expression though. I could put it in a lambda, but then it's already very close to AhmedAEK's suggestion.

@einpoklum   In other words - purely subjective concerns.

I asked a similar question 7 years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45149760/4641116  (Now, 7 years later... still no sugar.
And the DIY sugar (like milleniumbug's) tastes funny.)

How do you intend to use the result of obj?.x?

@j6t: Same way you use every optional. This is a general/abstract question after all.

Is there any technical hurdle to adding operator?. to C++?  It's incredibly useful in .NET.  Maybe it's not as common to need to do nested null checks in C++.

@Craig: The techcnical hurdle is writing the paper and getting the committee to vote for it... but more seriously: It would affect tokenization somewhat, although this shouldn't be a big deal. There's the need to define the semantics in a way which agrees with everything in the language and the standard library; considering whether it should be overloadable; and making sure it's useful not just for optionals.

@einpoklum Well yes, re writing/submitting/voting, I'm aware of that hurdle.  That's not really a "technical" hurdle so much as a process hurdle.  I was thinking more about some sort of a showstopper issue with parsing it (e.g. if it had already been used as a digraph, something like that).

@Craig: I think digraphs are gone by now, so that won't be it. And parsing-wise - I don't think you can have any valid-parsable program with a . following a ?: ? is the trinary operator, and you can't start an expression with a dot, AFAICR. So that part should be fine. In terms of fitting in - remember that in JS, null is kind of universal, but in C++ we have nullptr, std::nullopt, std::monostate and maybe some other critters, all of which might serve as arguments against introducing this operator.

@einpoklum To be precise, an expression can start with a dot – a floating-point literal doesn't need to start with a digit.

@ach: Oh, damn, you're right. So, this might break existing code then: x = cond?.5:.6;

C++23 introduced Monadic operations for optional, so you can use std::optional::transform
#include <optional>

using Bar = int;
struct Foo { Bar x; };

std::optional<Bar> f()
{
    std::optional<Foo> obj {};
    return obj.transform([](auto&& o) { return o.x;});
}

for lower C++ versions you could use C++11 optional library which has a similar operation (map), or write your own version of transform (not recommended).
godbolt demo
I don't recommend you write you own transform because to make it chainable you need to inherit from std::optional, and it is likely UB to inherit from the standard library objects.

A shorter version would define the lambda as a struct externally, if you are using it everywhere and need to reduce the number of letters per use. (with the exact same assembly)
template <typename Member>
struct grab
{
    Member member;
    auto operator()(auto& obj) const 
    { return obj.*member; }
};

std::optional<Bar> f()
{
    std::optional<Foo> obj {};
    return obj.transform(grab{&Foo::x});
}


Are you sure you want to propose that? I mean, obj?.x is 2 characters plus the variable and field names. obj.transform([]auto&& o) { return o.x; }) is 39 characters plus the variable and field names: 19.5 times more text. Can we really do no better than that?

@einpoklum the alternative is not something i should ever recommend https://godbolt.org/z/5xehjn9KM

FWIW it's not recommended to publicly inherit from standard classes.  Private inheritance is fine.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector

I was surprised to discover C++ option lacked a map method, but after a few minutes thought, it seems easy to emulate.
template<class I, class O>
std::optional<O> map(const std::optional<I>& val, O const I::*member)
{ return val ? std::optional<O>{*val.*member} : std::nullopt; }

template<class I, class O, class...Args>
std::optional<O> map(const std::optional<I>& val, O (I::*method)() const, Args&&...args)
{ return val ? std::optional<O>{(*val.*method)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)} : std::nullopt; }

And then usage is terse:
map(obj, &Foo::x);
map(obj, &Foo::getX); //if you need to pass parameters to this, you can

This only works on members and methods, and not arbitrary function calls, but arbitrary functinon calls would require lambdas, which are annoyingly verbose in C++.

I like this but its a shame its not chainable.

member pointers seem to clinch it. I wonder... is there a paper asking for this feature in the library?

Also - won't this have problems with references?

@einpoklum This returns by copy, since std::optional doesn't support references.

@MooingDuck: Let me rephrase, because I actually asked multiple questions in one... 1. rvalue optionals as input to map (so can't take a const&); 2. fields which are references - I guess you addressed that.

const& accepts rvalues. It doesn't preserve the rvalueness... which is moot due to lack of references :/

A hacky, but arguably more fun, tweak of Mooing Duck's answer would let us use:
map(obj, x)

instead of Javascript's obj?.x.
Yes, it's this simple because macros are involved >:-)
#include <optional>
#include <type_traits>

using Bar = int;
struct Foo { Bar x; };

template<class I, class O>
std::optional<O> map_impl(const std::optional<I>& val, O const I::*member)
{ return val ? std::optional<O>{*val.*member} : std::nullopt; }

#define map(obj_, field_) map_impl(obj_, &std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*obj_)> :: field_ )

Notes:

See this working on GodBolt.
Would need some adaptation to also work for methods rather than just data fields, but I'm pretty sure some TMP can make that happen.
We would probably not use this name, to avoid clashing with std::map and other uses of the word map - a macro is much more "syntactically-imperialistic". So maybe something like qdot.
If we apply @milleniumbug's infix operator generator, we might even be able to make it into a proper infix operator, which we would get us close to nirvana with obj qdot x.


Here's a variation that works in c++17 (if you delete the concepts) and supports chaining.  I opted for return by value.  One could incorporate perfect forwarding if performance is a concern.
#include <cassert>
#include <optional>
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
struct is_optional : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_optional<std::optional<T>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_optional_v = is_optional<T>::value;

template <typename T>
concept IsOptional = is_optional_v<T>;

template<typename T, class O>
IsOptional auto operator |(const std::optional<T>& obj, O const T::*member)
{
    if constexpr (is_optional_v<O>) {
        return obj ? (*obj).*member : std::nullopt;
    }
    else {
        return obj ? std::optional<O>{(*obj).*member} : std::nullopt;
    }
}

template<typename T, class O>
IsOptional auto operator |(const T& obj, O const T::*member)
{
    if constexpr (is_optional_v<O>) {
        return obj.*member;
    }
    else {
        return std::optional<O>{obj.*member};
    }
}


int main()
{
    using Bar = int;
    struct Foo {
        Bar x;
    };

    Foo foo{123};
    std::optional<Foo> foo2{Foo{123}};
    std::optional<Foo> foo3{};

    assert((foo | &Foo::x) == 123);
    assert((foo2 | &Foo::x) == 123);
    assert((foo3 | &Foo::x) == std::nullopt);
}

void chain()
{
    struct B {
        int x;
    };

    struct A {
        std::optional<B> b;
    };

    std::optional<A> val1;
    std::optional<A> val2 = A{};
    std::optional<A> val3 = A{B{123}};
    A val4 = A{B{123}};
    auto x1 = val1 | &A::b | &B::x;
    assert(!x1);
    auto x2 = val2 | &A::b | &B::x;
    assert(!x2);
    auto x3 = val3 | &A::b | &B::x;
    assert(*x3 == 123);
    auto x4 = (val4 | &A::b) | &B::x;
    assert(*x4 == 123);
}


is_optional – eek! This is modality confusion waiting to happen.

You have a point.  this approach will likely not work if Foo supports a member variable/method that also appears in std::optional.

(C++23)  With a little operator| overloading to do piping, and taking a page out of the monad playbook, could do something like...
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

using Bar = int;

struct Foo { Bar x; };

struct FFoo { std::optional<Bar> x{}; };

inline auto f(std::optional<Foo> obj) -> std::optional<Bar> {
    return obj ? obj->x : std::nullopt;
}

inline auto ff(std::optional<FFoo> obj) -> std::optional<Bar> {
    return obj ? obj->x : std::nullopt;
}

inline void println(std::optional<Bar> obj) {
    if (!obj) {
        std::cout << "(empty)\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << *obj << "\n";
    }
}

// C++23 magic to use operator| to pipe calls.
template <typename T, typename FN> requires (std::invocable<FN, T>)
constexpr auto operator|(T&& t, FN&& f) -> typename std::invoke_result_t<FN, T> {
    return std::invoke(std::forward<FN>(f), std::forward<T>(t));
}

int main() {
    std::optional<FFoo> no_foo;
    std::optional<FFoo> foo_no_bar{ Foo{} };
    std::optional<FFoo> foo_bar{ Foo{ 10 } };
    std::optional<Foo> original_foo{ Foo{ 20 } };
    std::optional<Foo> original_no_foo{};


    no_foo | ff | println;
    foo_no_bar | ff | println;
    foo_bar | ff | println;
    original_foo | f | println;
    original_no_foo | f | println;
}

Update:  renamed my modifed Foo to FFoo, f to ff, added the original Foo and original f back in, and added original_foo and original_no_foo objects to demonstrate use.

How does this answer my question? What is the expression I use instead of obj?.x? Also note that you're using a different struct Foo than in my question.

@einpoklum • I added in original_foo | f to show how you'd do the expression.

@Eljay I think this is a good example of why people correctly complain about C++. It gives too much power to programmers. Take this out of context. What is your no_foo | ff | println; doing? Answer who knows, it is not idiomatic C++.

@Questor • I agree with you on all points.  C++: the bugs practically write themselves.

Depending on use case you can use either of 4 monadic functions:

Get the intact value, if exists or provide a default value: optional::value_or. This method expects a default value.

std::optional<Foo> optfoo;
Foo foo = foo.value_or(Foo{});


Replace current value, in case it exists or return nullopt with optional::transform:

std::optional<Foo> optfoo;
std::optional<Bar> optbar = foo.transform(&Foo::x);

This method can change the result type from optional<foo> to optional<bar>.

Convert current value to an optional -which may be null- via optional::and_then.

std::optional<Foo> optfoo;
std::optional<Bar> optbar = foo.and_then([](Foo& foo){
    return std::optional{foo.x};
});

The difference from transform is that the lambda returns an optional.

Replace the value with an optional of same type, if it is null with optional::or_else:

std::optional<Foo> optfoo;
std::optional<Foo> optfoo2 = foo.or_else([]{
    return std::optional{Foo{}};
});

This method keeps the type of optional<foo>, but tries to replace the value(like value_or).
Option 1 is the only C++17 solution and the only one that doesn't take a lambda/function as its input, and the only one that doesn't necessarily return an optional.Other options need C++23, return optional values and need function inputs.

Two of the items here don't seem to answer my question, and one of the others already appears as another answer.

The only good answer here... And OP doesn't like it

@einpoklum there's no special operator for that use case in C++. optional is a relatively new type in software domain. And as long as sth can be implemented with code, it won't be part of C++ core. These are the 4 methods that avoid explicit check for validity an optional instance. I would avoid the rest of methods for all sorts of UB/exception involved. If you want to be safe, limit yourself to assignment, constructors and the above monadic API. Wether or not you like it, that's all there is.

@Red.Wave: 1. optional is not a relatively new type. 2. You're suggesting that C++ never introduces syntactic sugar - which is not the case. We got the spaceship operator, for example. 3. "I would avoid" - if you avoid things which may throw exceptions you're going to have a hard time in life... as for UB - certainly we don't want UB. 4. We can be perfectly safe with ?..


I would call C++17 relatively new. Because C++ is a bit older than myself. 2. The spaceship operator has properties that are impossible to reproduce in code, so that's entirely irrelevant and invalid. 3. I have my choices and of-course recommend the ones that can benefit everyone. The monadic interface of optional and expected covers their most common use cases; in fact that's what any decent reference recommends. 4. Conditional operator has its own pitfalls regarding common type and the requirement of 3 operands makes it uninteresting for the OP case.

